# Authentication of User on Firebase in C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am searching for one week on the topic of how to authenticate a specific user on firebase using email and password and then retrieve data for that specific user if it is registered in C# app?

I tried a lot but unable to find the correct way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure you only post *after* you have at least searched somewhere for an answer. A quick google search led me to here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet, which seems perfect for your needs. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have searched a lot and find that too but the thing is I am new to the C# and firebase, so I need a solution with a coding example if someone can help?

Comment: Maybe this helps you:  
https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-c-library-5c342989ad18  
https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-c-library-8e5e1c30acc2